# Is totally separated space equivalent to null dimensional and $T_0$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, separation-axioms

It is a well known fact that every [null dimensional](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Zero-dimensional_space) $T_0$ space is [totally separated](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Totally_Separated_Space).

Is there an example of a totally separated space that is not null dimensional or $T_0$, or does the converse of the upper fact hold too?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I don’t see why Erdős space $H_0$ from the deleted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3472911) by S.S.Danyal is not [totally separted](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Totally_Separated_Space) . I think we can show this as follows. Let $x=(x_i)_{i\in\omega}$  and $y=(y_i)_{i\in\omega}$ be distinct points of $H_0$. So there exists an index $i$ such that $x_i\ne y_i$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $x_i<y_i$.

Comment: Pick any irrational number $q$ between $x_i$ and $y_i$ and put $U=\{(z_j)_{j\in\omega}\in H_0: z_i<q\}$ and $V=\{(z_j)_{j\in\omega}\in H_0: z_i>q\}$. Then $x\in U$, $y\in V$ and $U|V$ is a [separation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Separation_(Topology)) of $H_0$, right?